# How to use local ssh config alias in kinit over ssh?

Tags: ssh

I need login jump machine(let say jump.example.com) use `ssh jump.example.com` firstly, and then type `kinit` and input my password, now I can type my host I want to connect like `ssh user@1.2.3.4`, but I write many aliases in .ssh/config, e.g.:

```
Hostname foo
  User user
  Host 1.2.3.4
```

in this case I can't just write `ssh jump.exmaple.com ssh foo` because ssh config is in local instead jump machine. How to solve this?

P.S.: I can use `ssh jump.example.com -tt ssh user@1.2.3.4` but I can't memorize so many IPs.

Comment: I use `ssh -J jump.example.com ssh ppe -vvv` it returns `channel 0: open failed: unknown channel type: unknown channel type: direct-tcpip`, have no idea what's wrong and how to debug it

Comment: Does `ssh -J jump.example.com 1.2.3.4` (or ppe or instead of 1.2.3.4) work? When using `-J`, you usually don't need to explicitly call ssh on the jump host.

Comment: @Wieland I tried but it return same error, my first comment write duplicate ssh